# Not able to extract files to the icons folder

Tags: icons, clipboard, extract

I downloaded some icons for Ubuntu from a site as a tar.bz2 folder. Now when bi try to extract the icons to my icons folder in the system i am getting the following message- Extraction not performed

```
You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "file:///usr/share/icons"
```

How can i copy the icons please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract them to your Home folder .icons folder instead, note that the folder is hidden.

If it's not there create it.

Now answering your question, the error is telling you exactly why you can't you don't have permissions. The folder is owned by root, you're not root and you don't have to be for this, you can extarct them to any folder in your Home folder, then use `gksu nautilus`to move the to the usr/share/icons folder.

Comment: i am new to Ubuntu so can u pls tell me what is gksu nautilus

Comment: `gksu`gives you access to elevated privileges to access and modify system owned files and folders, if you launch Nautilus using gksu you can move the Icons to usr/ once you're done close that nautilus window.

Comment: How do I launch Nautilus using gksu

Comment: Press Alt+f2 and type it, or press Control+t to open a Terminal window and type it.